# Apply sort using python(not QuerySet) to models using ListView pagination

Tags: python, django, listview, django-models, pagination

## Apply sort using python(not QuerySet)  to models using ListView pagination

I use Django ListView with pagination feature to display models.

Since I need to sort list of models using method field(need to send param to method thus it must be a method) return value, I cannot complete sorting using get_query_set method.

Since get_context_data is called for each page, I cannot add sort to there.

```
class SpotRankingView(ListView):

    model = Spot
    template_name = 'places/spot_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SpotRankingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # This is called for every page
        # So I cannot add sort here

        return context


    def get_queryset(self):

        # I need method return value to sort models
        #
        # ex. I need something like blow to sort models
        # method category as blow is a calculated property on model.
        # spot.category(category_name = 'Relaxing').points
        #
        # Those cannot be done by QuerySet so I caanot add that
        # sorting here

        return Spot.objects.all()
```

How can I sort models using python list sorting & make them paginate?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of sorting you need. There are a lot of sorting methods like by date, by id, by reverse date. Since you are using `Class Based Views` you can use `ArchiveIndexView` like below.

```
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView

class SpotRankingView(ArchiveIndexView):

     model = Spot
     template_name = 'places/spot_list.html'
     paginate_by = 5
     date_field = "date_created"
```

You need to set `allow_future` to `True` if you want to show objects with date in future. If you still don't understand then follow the [reference](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.dates/ArchiveIndexView/).

You also can do this for your list view like:

```
class SpotRankingView(ListView):

    model = Spot
    template_name = 'places/spot_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_ordering(self):
         ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', '-date_created')
```

Comment: According to the doc, get_ordering applies ordering to queryset.  Since I need ordering cannot be done directly by db, I still cannot solve my problem